# Regarding the identity of user and admin

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

When we are deploying our hyperledger network where are these identity of user and admin stored and how is user authenticated

Comment: Have you seen the Hyperledger Fabric Key Concepts document - particularly the section on Identity?  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/identity/identity.html

Answer (score 1):

I hyperledger fabric total three identities

**CA-Admin**: certificate authority admin

```
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b nbdadmin:nbdpw -d'
```

**Org-Admin**: we will register and enroll this admin and submit to all MSP's

**User**: Normal user

**Storage**:
User certs can be stored in KVS (File Store), data store(couchDB)